# How to validate a string property using RegularExpressionAttribute, by throwing an exception, if validation fails in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, api, .net-core

I am writing a simple .NET Core 3.1 API application. I would like to validate MailAddress by using C# built in RegularExpressionAttribute, and then save my validated entities to the database using EF Core. Here's my sample code:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$")]
    public string MailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

I expected , that if i am going to assign a regex not matching value, an exception will be thrown.

```
var newUser = new UserEntity()
            { MailAddress = signUpData.MailAddress, Username = signUpData.Username, PasswordHash = passwordHash };
```

Nothing happens here, the application continues it's execution and UserEntity is being saved to my database. I would like an exception to be thrown if mail validation fails. How to achieve that? Do i have to explicitly call Regex.Match(), instead of using attribute, to check the passed string correctness? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you limited from validating it using decorator? might as well validate it on controller/service layer.

Comment: It should be clarified, signUpData.MailAddress is obviously improper while constructing UserEntity, and still nothing happens

Comment: @jersoft you mean, calling Regex.Match(signUpData.MailAddress, @"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$")? And throw and exception basing on it's result right? By the way where such a validation should be carried out, in a service layer?

Comment: Do you just need to add the error message for the regex check? Like `[RegularExpression(@"^[\w.-]+@[\w-]+(?:\.\w{2,3})+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct email.")]` (I removed redundant regex parts).

Comment: @Bulchsu- Yes. In our team, we are not fully leveraging decorators as it limits our code and sometimes it violate clean code principles. Yes, you may put the validations on service layer.'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't solve this :(